# Kotlin in Android Studio wont load an HTTP audio link. HTTPS works fine

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building a radio streaming app and a link i have with https works great but when i put in one for a different stream that is just http, the app hangs and then crashes.

I have tried adding few lines to the `Manifest` but it's still not having it.

Manifest file looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
>
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
        <meta-data

            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/network_security_config"

            />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my `network_security_config.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://s3.voscast.com:9532</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">

        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>

    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

i get this in the Logcat so maybe the config file isn't being loaded:

`D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default`

Comment: See here. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your manifest file, application tag is closed before setting "usesCleartextTraffic"

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Fix it and try again. It'll work. Everything else looks good

Comment: Yeeeeeah boi!! Worked great. Classic case of staring at the screen too long to see an obvious error. Thanks